# Console.log dont work correctly on Karma/Jasmine

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine

I have a structure as

```
myObject={
   Items:[
   {
    namePizza:{}
    quantity: int
   }
   {
    namePizza:{}
    quantity: int
   }
  ]
}
```

---

If a try `console.log(myObject) Karma always return  LOG:{Items:[]}`

I dont understand why happen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal `console.log` will show you the inner content of the the javascript objects

```
> console.log({1,2})
> Object { 1, 2 }
```

**BUT why does calling `console.log` through karma behaves differently!**

Digging into the karma code; Karma modifies the original `console` to extract the messages and add metadata to each log. So in order to have a safe logger and to be able to log everything given to them as arguments, these libraries `stringify` the data you pass to the logger.

Here is what is exactly happening in karma logger:

```
values.push(this.stringify(args[i], 3))
```

as you can see, they have their own implementation of the logger.

The modified logger calls [`stringify`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/common/stringify.js) against the data you send.

You can check the karma logger where the "stringifying" happens here: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/context/karma.js#L16

Practically most test runners or logging transports (example ravenJS for sentry) do such things.

**To solve this issue; wrap your object with `JSON.stringify` when calling `console.log`**

Note that `JSON.stringify` will not work with `Sets` or `Maps` and their `weak` counterpart. For those you have to call `.values()` against them to get the logger working correctly!

Comment: Your answers I think that is correct but my problem dont solved, but really is a problem encapsulation of classes on my javascript, I need do `test.order[pizza.hash]` for see some in my console.log, as say this your answer is correct, not solved my problem for my encapsulation but its good :)